# Did I miss the Institute quests?

Tags: achievements, fallout-4

I think I might have missed the Institute quests when I didn't agree to help her. Can I go back to the location and get it? If so where is the location? Please help as I believe I need these for PS4 achievements and 100 percent completion.

Answer (score 1):

"Institutionalized" is a main story quest and cannot be skipped but in order to get the achievement you must follow the Institute quest line instead of any of the other factions.

If you choose another faction to enter the Institute during the mission The Molecular Level, you'll end up doing part of the Institutionalized questline in many instances (for example, the Railroad quests have you continue the Institute quests concurrently with their own to avoid arousing suspicion of the Institute) but you'll not complete the required mission to get the Institutionalized achievement.

Comment: I went through my completed quests and Institutionalized is not there and it is not active. How do I start it. Im level 27 so im well through it. So if I dont follow the institute I cant get 100 percent completion? But are there not achievments for the other factions too?

Comment: Have you completed The Molecular Level? Have you met Father and if so have you done missions for him? (I'd guess not if they're not in your quest log)

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks very much! I turned a woman down because I thought was from the institute earlier on and I thought I had missed those quests. Still cant figure out who she was. She was in a lab coat.

Comment: perhaps Dr. Amari from Goodneighbor?